# C++ How do I get the data out of a templated child of a virtual class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, containers, virtual

So I have this class and I need to get the data stored in the _data variable somehow.

```
template<typename T>
class gNode : public BaseSuperclass {
private:
    int _id;
    T _data;
public:

    gNode(int id, T data) {
        _id = id;
        _data = data;
    }

    const int getId() { return _id; }

    T getData(){
        return _data;
    }
};
```

This class is inherited from this virtual class, since I need to store the gNode class in a container and that would not work because of the container.

```
class BaseSuperclass {
// ...
public:
    virtual const int getId() = 0;
};
```

This container will be the only way I can access the gNode objects. But now I am at a loss, as to how to retreive the data in the _data variable, since the virtual class can't have a function with a unknown return type.

Thats the container:

```
vector<BaseSuperclass *> nodes;
```

The code below gives me a segmentation error.

```
gNode<T>* node1 = dynamic_cast<gNode<T>*>(nodes[0]);
node1->getData();
```

I appreciate every help I can get.
Thanks.

**edit:** I found out that this segmentation fault happens if the gNode._data have different types. So if I only pass int or only strings, everything is fine. But if the first gNode is a string and the second an int, it goes wrong. Doesn't make sense to me still

**edit2:**
requested compilable (I think) example:
    #include 
    #include

```
using namespace std;
class BaseSuperclass {
public:
    virtual const int getId() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class gNode : public BaseSuperclass {
private:
    int _id;
    T _data;
public:

    //Konstruktor
    gNode(int id, T data) {
        _id = id;
        _data = data;
    }

    const int getId() { return _id; }

    T getData(){
        return _data;
    }
};

class Graph {
public:
    vector<BaseSuperclass *> nodes;

    template<typename T>
    void addNode(int nodeId, T data) {      


        nodes.push_back(new gNode<T>(nodeId, data));
        gNode<T>* node1 = dynamic_cast<gNode<T>*>(nodes[0]);
        T test = node1->getData();
        cout<<test<<endl;
};
void Main(){
Graph graph1;
graph1.addNode(1, "vvv");
graph1.addNode(2, 12);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to check if the `dynamic_cast` was successfully, i.e if there is a valid ptr in `node1`.

Comment: Heh I knew before even looking at your profile that this was Part 2 of the `void*` story :)

Comment: Are you positive `nodes[0]` is actually a `gNode<T>*`?  The segfault hints that it's probably a different type.

Comment: @StephenNewell it should be. Or is: 'nodes.push_back(new gNode<T>(nodeId, data));' wrong in any way?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes that thread was very helpul but I keep hitting wall after wall with this one

Comment: `gNode<T>* node1 = dynamic_cast<gNode<T>*>(nodes[0]);` What is `T` here? Could you add a complete and compilable example where you add and then try to extract a value with a valid type?

Comment: @MaxVollmer the T is the type of a Template to that function. I'll try and add the compilable example.

Comment: If you have different types, you need to dynamic_cast with the correct type for each vector element you access.

Comment: @MaxVollmer added the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `addNode` you `push_back` with type `T`, and then try to access the first element with type `T` as well.

You call `addNode` twice, with two different types.

So the second time you call `addNode`, `T` is different from the type stored in the first element. Thus `dynamic_cast<gNode<T>*>(nodes[0]);` will return a `nullptr`.

You need to make sure that you use the same type when reading that you used when storing.

Comment: Yes thank you this was it. I've been looking too long at this. Cheers!